# How to authenticate server-to-server interactions in Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm implementing an appengine cloud endpoint that only a Jenkins instance that I own should have access to. Based on the documentation I've read, server-to-server interactions should use service accounts, but I could only find how to set this up for Google APIs.

From what I understand, google cloud endpoints, even with CLIENT_IDs set, still need a user.

What is the correct approach to accomplish this?

Thanks!